# Как сразу текст выставить по середине?

Tags: svg

Как сразу не подбирая координаты по x и y поставить текст по середине ?

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
  <circle r="20" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="#03BE9B" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text x="13" y="10" fill="red">text</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите для текста:

```
x="50%" 
y="50%"  
text-anchor="middle" 
dominant-baseline="central"
```

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"
 style="border:1px solid crimson" viewBox='0 0 50 50'>
  <circle r="20" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="#03BE9B" stroke-width="2"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">text</text>
</svg>
```